# OKTA SSO for SPA application

Tags: angular, single-sign-on, okta

I am trying to implement SSO with Okta for my Angular 7 application. I have installed `@okta/angular` and all the dependencies. If the user is not logged in to okta already, it will be redirect to Okta. once i enter my credentials and redirect back to angular, then I encounter an issue as below.

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'id_token'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'id_token'
    at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (vendor.js:146954)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (vendor.js:146935)
    at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (vendor.js:220440)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (vendor.js:217181)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (vendor.js:217161)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (vendor.js:217181)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (vendor.js:217161)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (vendor.js:217181)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (vendor.js:217161)
    at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._error (vendor.js:225180)
    at resolvePromise (polyfills.js:3696)
    at resolvePromise (polyfills.js:3653)
    at polyfills.js:3757
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3267)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js:78548)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3266)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (polyfills.js:3039)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (polyfills.js:3445)
```

Comment: Fixed this issue. It was due to use of Hashing strategy. 
Can anyone please help me out with OKTA SSO working by not replacing  useHash:true

Answer (score 0):

Which okta-angular version are you using ?

What kind of routing are you using ?

Comment: @okta/okta-angular - v1.4.0  
I was using Hash Location Strategy which would append hash at the end of route paths.. This caused error in SSO. Hence currently using PathLocationStrategy